# Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing

Tags: java, spring, grails, jar, spring-loaded

When I am running "grails run-app -Dserver.port=8005" getting followin error. Please somebody help me on this. Thanks in advance!!

Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : E:/work/ThirdParty/grails-2.4.3/lib/org.springframework/springloaded/jars/springloaded-1.2.0.RELEAS
E.jar
Error occurred during initialization of VM
agent library failed to init: instrument

Answer (score 0):

Its happening for Grails home path. You need to set your grails home path correctly.[image]

Comment: I have set the GRAILS_HOME. and given in the path like %GRAILS_HOME%\bin already:)

Comment: Refresh your project by `grails clean` then run